# spring effect in box2djs

Tags: box2d, box2dweb

I want to simulate spring effect using box2djs.
After a lot search i figure it that that distancejoint can be used (i am not sure).
I tried the follwing code but i am not looking any joint between the body.

```
 distance_joint = new b2DistanceJointDef();

distance_joint.body1 = Body1;

distance_joint.body2 = Body2;

distance_joint.localAnchorA = new b2Vec2(0, 0);

distance_joint.localAnchorB = new b2Vec2(0, 0);

distance_joint.length = 3;

distance_joint.collideConnected = true;

return world.CreateJoint(distance_joint);
```

Any idea...

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are right, distance joint can be used as the spring. This is said in the Box2D manual:

> The distance joint can also be made soft, like a spring-damper connection. See the Web example in the testbed to see how this behaves.
>
> Softness is achieved by tuning two constants in the definition: frequency and damping ratio. Think of the frequency as the frequency of a harmonic oscillator (like a guitar string). The frequency is specified in Hertz. Typically the frequency should be less than a half the frequency of the time step. So if you are using a 60Hz time step, the frequency of the distance joint should be less than 30Hz. The reason is related to the Nyquist frequency.
>
> The damping ratio is non-dimensional and is typically between 0 and 1, but can be larger. At 1, the damping is critical (all oscillations should vanish).
>
> ```
> jointDef.frequencyHz = 4.0f;
> jointDef.dampingRatio = 0.5f;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, now second part of the problem...why there is no any distance joint formed between two bodies...is there any problem in the code...i can post more code if necesssary...

Comment: for refernce this is my main function-> '$(function() 
{
   world = createWorld();

    canvas = document.getElementById('game');  
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
             
    canvas_width = parseInt(canvas.width);
    canvas_height = parseInt(canvas.height);
      
    createGround(canvas_width / 2, canvas_height - iBorder, canvas_width / 2, iBorder, 0);
    
    Body1 = CreateObject1();
    Body2 = CreateObject2();
    
 CreateJoint();

     $(canvas).mousedown(function()
    {
  ChangePosition();
    }); 
 
 frame();
});'

Comment: Tell please, what returns CreateJoint method.

Answer (score 0):

CreateJoint returns b2Joint(the joint created), but that is not the issue...
I found out the issue.
Actually i was setting local anchor point as

`distance_joint.localAnchorA = new b2Vec2(0, 0);`

`distance_joint.localAnchorB = new b2Vec2(0, 0);`

rather i should created the anchor point in the world like

`distance_joint.anchorPoint1.Set(0.0, 0.0);`

`distance_joint.anchorPoint2.Set(0.0, 0.0);`

Now, the joint is created correctly.
One more issue...since i am trying to implement spring effect i try to set anchor point in the middle of the sencond body, but i am not getting success.

any idea..

Thanks